# How to use joins(inner,left) with xmltable?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, xmltable

I have a xml like below,

```
<a_level1>
 <level2>
  <list1>
   <a1>123456</a1>
   <list2>
    <variables>
     <a2>115</a2>
     <a3>1313.57</a3>
     <a4>asd</a4>
    </variables>
   </list2>
  </list1>
  <list1>
   <a1>1072001</a1>
   <list2>
    <variables>
     <a2>215</a2>
     <a3>2740.18</a3>
     <a4>qwe</a4>
    </variables>
   </list2>
  </list1>
 </level2>
</a_level1>
```

I can extract variables from xmltype to table like this.

```
select a.a1,b.a2,b.a3,b.a4
from x.x_table t,
  xmltable(
    '/a_level1/level2/list1'
    PASSING xmltype(t.xml_data)
    COLUMNS a1 varchar2(20) PATH 'a1',
      list2 XMLType PATH 'list2'
  ) a,
  xmltable(
    '/list2/variables'
    PASSING a.list2
    COLUMNS a2 varchar2(20) PATH 'a2',
      a3 varchar2(20) PATH 'a3',
      a4 varchar2(20) PATH 'a4'
    ) b 
where t.xml_id = 1
```

result is;

| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 115 | 1313.57 | asd |
| 123456 | 215 | 2740.18 | qwe |

my question is how can i use inner join in this query

Comment: You may add a `where` clause to the query

Comment: there is also I have added where clasue

Comment: Do you mean within the query you have now - in which case what are you trying to achieve? Or to join your result to another table you haven't mentioned - in which case the same as any other join? You haven't said what's wrong with your current result, or how you want to extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any `INNER JOIN`s, or even the second `XMLTABLE`, as you can use the full path from the second table and then go back up the hierarchy to get the `a1` value:

```sql
select a.*
from   /*x.*/x_table t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/a_level1/level2/list1/list2/variables'
         PASSING xmltype(t.xml_data)
         COLUMNS
           a1 varchar2(20) PATH './../../a1',
           a2 varchar2(20) PATH 'a2',
           a3 varchar2(20) PATH 'a3',
           a4 varchar2(20) PATH 'a4'
       ) a
where  t.xml_id = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123456 | 115 | 1313.57 | asd |
> | 1072001 | 215 | 2740.18 | qwe |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d7355062cd072d92ee632eeef2170303)*